# The most efficient way to get a hall of fame/shame in a photo rating system like this

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a hall of fame and hall of shame combined with a rating system.
the database looks like

```
CREATE TABLE photos(
    photo_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    photo_title VARCHAR(255),
    photo_path VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(photo_id)
);
CREATE TABLE ratings(
    rating_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    photo_id INT(11),
    rating_value INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY(rating_id)
);
```

In php what would be the most efficient method to create a list where a certain amount of photographs are ordered by the amount of ratings they've received?

Comment: Just an unrelated question.... what's preventing people from voting multiple times on the same picture?

Comment: Which bits do you need to do in php? Querying and ordering is stuff you'd do in the database. (You might also want to add dates to the photos and / or votes so you can prioritise recent popular photos, etc.)

Comment: wait: is this facemash from 'The Social Network"?!? You're a tad late!

Comment: @fingerman nothing is, its merely a similiar scenario, the actual db is somewhat more expanded. @Rup i just wonder how to query it to get the results the most efficiently, for examp. @mitch wheat i suppose you could do that with it aswell buts it more a photograph rating thing, pictures of mountains, ocean etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could add a attribute to the photos table in which you keep track of the total score and whenever some sort of specific history is required you can retrieve it from the ratings table. Possibly a cronjob or something to update the hall of fame/shame each hour or just whenever a rating is done update the users total score.

hope that helps!